# Symfony2 MongoDB persisted object is not saved to database

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

i have object Ticket in my database with such a structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("549803361bac2fa81a000029"),
  "amount" : 1,
  "price" : 123000,
  "phone" : "+111 (11) 111-11-11",
  "status" : 1,
  "is_admin_added" : 1,
  "created" : ISODate("2014-12-22T11:39:52.000Z"),
  "event" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("549803361bac2fa81a00002a"),
    "name" : "helicopter",
    "start_date" : ISODate("2014-12-31T08:11:00.000Z"),
    "city" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("549026601bac2f5811000033"),
        "name" : "cityname"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my yml config for the Ticket object:

```
Bnv\BnvBundle\Document\Ticket:
  fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    amount:
        type: int
    price:
        type: int
    phone:
        type: string
    additional:
        type: string
    status:
        type: int
    is_admin_added:
        type: int
    created:
        type: date
    user_id:
        type: int
  repositoryClass: Bnv\BnvBundle\Repository\TicketRepository
  embedOne:
    event:
        targetDocument: Event
        cascade: all
```

I can normally save new Ticket object and its new descendants - object Event and object City - when i create the Ticket object.

But i can't save new value of name of embed document Event if i try to edit the value. Here is my code for editing:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$ticket = $dm->getRepository('BnvBnvBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
$ticket->setPrice($price);
$ticket->setPhone($phone);
$event = $ticket->getEvent();
$event->setName($eventName);
$dm->persist($ticket);
$dm->persist($event);
$dm->flush();
```

Here price and phone of the Ticket are successfully saved, but name of the Event is not changed in database (event name is changed only in object when i debug the code above, but not in database after flush)

I can't understand why. Help me, please, understand, what's the reason for that. Thank you.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: yes, I clear it every time I change config or code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. A Method

```
$this->mongoCollection->update($query, $newObj, $options);
```

in `vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Collection.php` actually changes the object Event **in collection** "Event" - **not** the embedded object Event **in the object** Ticket. So i think either embed documents in mongodb are not suitable for editing or I missed some settings in telling symfony that event is embed document.

#### EDIT:

such a behavior was due to not existing `type: embeddedDocument` (first letter - lowercase) in yml config. Without this string document Event was saved in separate collection each time i added a new document Ticket